# Onresize event isn't running on resizing

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, disqus

I set the javascript window.onresize event to run other functions that fit div's size with the body's size. The problem is that when the screen is resized by adding a comment (using disqus), the divs whose sizes are supposed to fit with the new body's size, don't fit. I mean onresize function isn't being ran.

[image]

As you can see, the right side div doesn't grow as comments are being added (see the border). Do you have any idea about how make onresize event work?

PS: When I open developer tools on firefox, the div is resized, I don't know why, but the onresize event is ran. Only in this situation.

**Edit:** Tried to run this jquery script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"                          type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        $(document).resize(function(){
            tamanho_barra();
        });
</script>
```

But, isn't working yet. I've tried to change the "document" to a random div and see if something would happen, but nothing. I have no idea about what is the problem. Could you help me please?

**Edit2**: Working now with rcabral's help. He told me to add a background image to the content which is a black point of 1px and repeat it until the bottom of the page.

```
#content { background:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/gray_dot.gif') 634px 0px repeat-y; }
```

Comment: `document` is not the same thing as `window`

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: Adding content to the page makes the `document` 'resize'; not the `window`.

Comment: Oh so, is there a event which is ran when the document is resized or another way to resize the div?

Comment: @JoãoVinholi use media queries

Comment: Jason, could you tell me which are the advantages of the use of media queries?

Answer (score 3):

Your script isn't run automatically. You must include it inside a function that is run when the DOM is ready: $(document).ready(function() { here }); or $(function() { here });

For example:

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $("#barra").tamanho_barra();
        });
});
</script>
```

And your code has a few errors:
1. You are using two opening parentheses after "resize" instead of just one.
2. And you should select window instead of document for the resize function.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks rcabral, solved some questions that I had. But the problem insists because I what I want is to run tamanho_barra(); function when the document's size is changed, not when the window's is changed. Do you know some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery plugin that will let you target the container element that Disqus is running in.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/S3R7w/

Here's the plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

And here's the syntax:

```
$('div#disqus-container').bind('resize', function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: I believe this can only be wired to the `window` object: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: But must have a way to do this, http://omgubuntu.co.uk comment's page has a border across the page which grows with new comments.

Comment: Ah you're both right but there's actually a jQuery plugin to fix that. Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/S3R7w/

Comment: @hansvedo, actually one should note that while suing this plugin, there is a performance overhead as it using polling. So it is a bit of an overkill to use this plugin.